# How to change the insert line break shortcut in LibreOffice Calc from Ctrl + Enter to Alt+ Enter?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

To stay within the same cell and go to the next line, in Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In Libre Calc, however, it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I would like to stick with the learned default.

How can I change the shortcut in Libre Calc?

In the settings I cannot find an "insert line break" option:

[image: Libre Calc Settings]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shortcut to [insert line breaks](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/breaking_lines.html) is always <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> on Mac, and cannot be customized.

You could use AutoHotKey to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> whenever <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed.

Writing a macro won't work because there's no way to get the active cursor of the cell in Calc. The following code inserts a line break at the end of the cell:

```
oCell = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
oCurs = oCell.getText().createTextCursor()
oText.insertControlCharacter(oCurs, Chr(10), False)
```

This works in Writer only:

```
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertLinebreak", "", 0, Array())
```

Comment: Wow, something so simple needs such a hardcore solution. Maybe I should post a suggestion to the LibreOffice developers... that their implemented shortcut is not standard and that the other shortcut should be enabled too.

Comment: @Avatar: Yes, you could file an enhancement bug. However, I have not heard anyone mention this issue until now, so there may not be enough interest. Functional or ease-of-use improvements are the priority for the devs, and getting the LO user interface to match that of MS Office or another suite is not going to be anyone's goal. Maybe instead of talking about what is "standard," simply say you want to customize the shortcut. Out of curiosity, can it be customized in MS Office? By the way, I tried Google Sheets just now, and conveniently, both shortcuts work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Then I will get used to CTRL ENTER for line breaks inside a cell. 